How does the type of attributes of UserRepresentation in Keycloak look like?
In the Keycloak documentation, it just shows that the type of attributes is Map of [array]. There is no illustration.
For a Java Map<K, V>, how does the Map of [array] look like, i.e. what're data types of K and V respectively?
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/latest/rest-api/index.html#UserRepresentation

attributes  is Map<String, List>

May I know the source? @ravthiru

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/representations/idm/AbstractUserRepresentation.java
